# Formula field builder/editor in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, formula-editor

I need to build a Formula field for an application using Vaadin. The formula field will need to be configurable by the user using predetermined variables.

The closest thing I have found to what we need can be found here http://www.knackhq.com/links/blogs/custom-equations-for-online-databases.html

has anyone built a UI and background code for something like this before?

Comment: Did you look at [CriteriaBuilder](https://vaadin.com/directory-preview#!addon/criteriabuilder) plugin ?

Comment: The UI is one end of the deal.  How do you plan to use your formulas further down the road or what is already there you want to write the UI for?